# Query multiple summary tables in the same select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have several monthly summary tables and I need to query all of them in the same report.  How would I go about doing that?  Below are a few ideas that I had that are not working.

aug_summary

sept_summary

oct_summary

```
`SELECT name, timestamp FROM aug_summary AND sept_summary AND oct_summary;`
```

?

```
`select * from '*_summary'`
```

?

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL? don't tag BOTH at the same time.

Comment: Are name, timestamp columns in all three tables? If so you can use a UNION

Comment: removed the mysql tag.  thanks @RaymondNijland.  They will have identical formats so I think a UNION will work.  Is there a way to UNION *?

Comment: Having one table for each month seems like a bad design to begin with. You should only have a single table with a column that tells for which month the summary is. You can always create a view that UNIONs all the tables. That way you only need to do it in one place.

Comment: What PostgreSQL version are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, the tables are actually named by month.  summary201711, summary_201712... etc.

Comment: That's still not an ideal design.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name true but PostgreSQL doesn't implement ideal partitioning (atleast not until version 10)... partitioning might be the reason behide his.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: for something like that, even the inheritance based partitioning would work just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options to deal with this problem.

The obvious one is to normalize your database and merge all the data into single table that contains a "month" column, identifying the month for which the data is.

This looks like some manually created "partitioning" scheme. So another choice you have is to convert that into a table that uses [Postgres' built-in partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html)

As a quick fix, you could simply create view that does a union on all the tables, that way you have that huge `UNION` only once in your database and you can use a simple `select * from summary_table` in your report.

The report job then doesn't need to be changed. You only change the view once you create a new summary table (something you also wouldn't need to do with a normalized model or partitioning)

---

You can create a function that loops through the available tables and returns the contents of each table:

```
create function get_summary()
  returns setof summary201711
as
$$
declare 
  l_sql text;
  l_rec record;
begin
  for l_rec in select schemaname, tablename 
               from pg_tables 
               where schemaname = 'public'
               and tablename like 'summary%' --<< adjust this to match your pattern
  loop
     l_sql = format('select * from %I.%I', l_rec.schemaname, l_rec.tablename);
     return query execute l_sql;
  end loop;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Which of the tables you use for the `returns setof summary201711` doesn't really matter as they all **have** to have an identical structure.

Once you have that function you can use it like this:

```
select *
from get_summary();
```

Not sure how fast that is going to be though. My guess is that a view (or any form of partitioning) will be faster.

Comment: Thank you.  I also consulted with a colleague and they recommended creating a view.  Appreciate the assistance!

Comment: A really good answer, especially because you explain how the tables should be stored (partitioning) and then give a clever solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, timestamp FROM aug_summary
 UNION
SELECT name, timestamp FROM sept_summary
 UNION
SELECT name, timestamp FROM oct_summary
```

Etc, etc.

Comment: is there a way to union *?  otherwise, I would have to update the job every month

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.